# JQuery event only fires once, even though it is triggered more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially, all input fields in the 'invoice-line' containers are *disabled* except the first one. When a user inputs any text into any of the fields belonging to the first 'invoice-line', I would like for the second invoice-line inputs to become enabled. When a user inserts any text into any of the input fields of the second invoice line I would like for the third invoice line's input fields to become enabled.

I worked out some jquery that SHOULD work to accomplish this, and it DOES but only for the first invoice-line. In other words, once the event is triggered once, it is never triggered again. If it was, my problem would be solved, as my code seems to work correctly but only 'onChange' of the first invoice-line element.

I have been trying to solve this one for a long long time, I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Markup:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
    echo '
    <div class="invoice-line">
        <div class="prod-id-cell"><input type="text" class="prod-id-input"></div>
        <div class="prod-name-cell">
            <input onKeyPress="search(this.value)" type="text" class="prod-name-input"/>
            <div class="smart-suggestions">
                    <!-- RESULT SUGGESTIONS WILL POPULATE HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price-cell"><input class="price-input" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="unit-price-cell"><input class="unit-price-input" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="num-kits-cell"><input class="num-kits-input" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="amount-cell"><input class="amount-input" type="text" /></div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

JQuery:

```
//regulate what lines are enabled / disabled
$('.invoice-line div input').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('.invoice-line:first div input').removeAttr('disabled');

$('.invoice-line div input').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent('.invoice-line').next().find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: note that `closest(x)` is cleaner than `parent().parent()`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you couldn't attach `change` handlers to `disabled` elements. Try delegating. I don't think it's true, though.

Comment: Verify in the dev-tools if the DOM tree is as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how I would go about delegating their parent? The DOM tree is as expected...

Comment: to delegate to document: `$(document).on('change','.invoice-line div input', function(){...})`

Comment: Delegating is best done to the closest ancestor of all targeted elements that definitely and persistently exists. `document` is such an ancestor.

Comment: @MHZ - If someone types into the first one, the second one should be enabled, but according to the question, if someone types into the second one the third one should be **disabled**, is'nt it already disabled?

Comment: @adeneo Good catch. I believe that's a typo.

Comment: that was a typo, which is now fixed.

Comment: And you don't have to delegate unless the elements are dynamic, you can attach event handlers to disabled elements. Have a look at the fiddles below and tell us a little more about what exactly it is you're trying to do ?

Comment: @adeneo I was trying to verify the handler did get attached.

Comment: @adeneo, I am trying to regulate what inputs fields are enabled. Initially, all invoice line inputs are disabled except the inputs belonging to the first invoice line. As text is entered into the last enabled invoice line input field, I would like for the NEXT sequential invoice line's input fields to become enabled, etc... does this clarify?

Comment: Maybe, something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/11/) ???

Comment: This is very close, but for some reason, it still only fires once, no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one `parent()` to many, targeting the `invoice-line` wrapper, then finding the `next()` `invoice-line` , and what your probably looking for is really the next div and then the containing input etc :

```
$('.invoice-line input').not(':first').prop('disabled',true)
                        .end().on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/8/)
    ​

Also changed it to keyup, so as to not need a blur event to trigger the activation of the next input.

**EDIT:**

according to the comments, maybe this is what you're after ?

```
$('.invoice-line').not(':first').find('input').prop('disabled',true);

$('input', '.invoice-line').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('.invoice-line').next('.invoice-line').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/9/)

**EDIT:**

Try this one:

```
$('.invoice-line').not(':first').find('input').prop('disabled',true);

$(document).on('keyup', '.invoice-line input', function() {
    $(this).closest('.invoice-line').next('.invoice-line').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: The last one looks good. Any idea why the original code didn't work after the first line?

Comment: @Adeneo, you last code is extremely close to what I need, however, it STILL only fires once, when I apply it to my code.

Comment: Are you changing the HTML dynamically when the function is executed somehow ?

Comment: YES I am using AJAX. If you look at 'smart-suggestions' class in my html, the contents of that div is created dynamically using ajax.

Comment: Try the latest one above. As a sidenote, that is the main problem right there, and @JanDvorak had it right in the comments above, so he should post a delegated version as an answer that you can accept.

Comment: OK, I found the problem! You're logic works perfectly when I manually key in input! However, I am using the dynamically generated text to set the val() of the input fields using jquery. So I am not keying in the values into the input fields in all cases. However, when I use the change function instead of keyup, it doesn't recognize the 'changed' input fields unless I manually key in the text.

Comment: Nope, no change event is fired when you change the value programatically. You'll have to fire the change event with `.trigger('change')` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
          // first all the inputs in the .invoice-line get disabled
$('.invoice-line input[type="text"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
         // then the first of all in this becomes enabled 
$('.invoice-line input[type="text"]:first').removeAttr('disabled');

         // then on change next input will be enabled for inputing the values
$('.invoice-line input[type="text"]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
});
```